# Gmail outage only on one computer

Tags: networking, mac, gmail

**Problem:** Gmail (and only Gmail) quits working for a period of 5-10 mins *only on one computer*.

- Problem occurs several times daily
- Does not appear to be any "triggering event" - user is simply using Gmail normally when the problem arises
- User can access their Gmail from other computers on same LAN
- User can access all other sites, including other Google sites, from affected computer
- After several mins of outage, Gmail will spontaneously resume normal operation on affected computer
- The problem occurs in all browsers (Chrome, FF, Safari)
- Computer: MacBook Pro, OSX 10.7.3, latest browsers

I find this very baffling.  Any advice welcome.

Comment: Wireless, wired? If first, test if it happens with wired connection as well. Not very likely but best to rule it out immediately.

Comment: A problem description of "quits working" is not very detailed. What happens when you try to access Gmail?

Comment: A `tcpdump` on the affected host at the time might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Have you cleared the cache on the affected browser?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked for DNS problems?

I have seen quite a few Macs with DNS Changer malware on them, and they often exhibit strange behaviour not unlike this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a network card issue, 
NIC could be a little messed up which confuses GMAIL. 
Is DHCP being used here? If so try using a static IP for this laptop.- If this works then change your network card.